# In Verilog how to I prevent a double input? ie a button press being seen twice

Tags: verilog, hardware, timing

Here's a very simple piece of code

```
module TopLevel(
input   [0] KEY,
input [0] SW,
output reg [9:0] LEDR
);
always@(posedge KEY[0]) 
begin
    LEDR[0]<=SW[0];
    LEDR[1]<=LEDR[0];
    LEDR[2]<=LEDR[1];
    LEDR[3]<=LEDR[2];
    LEDR[4]<=LEDR[3];
    LEDR[5]<=LEDR[4];
    LEDR[6]<=LEDR[5];
    LEDR[7]<=LEDR[6];
    LEDR[8]<=LEDR[7];
    LEDR[9]<=LEDR[8];
end
endmodule
```

The idea being it takes an input from a switch and every time a button is pressed it shifts the input down a line of LEDs, each one becoming the next with each press.

The issue is that in hardware sometimes one button press causes multiple shifts when only one should happen.  My assumption is that the physical button isn't a perfect on/off clock and sometimes ones press is seen as multiple rising edges simply due to real world imperfections.

Is there a way to resist that?  as in: "Do this whenever button is pressed, but only once per millisecond" or some kinds of hysteresis?

I guess I could use an internal millisecond clock to just poll rather than triggering on the button, but I'm curious if cleaning up a button input directly is possible.

I tried doing things like #10; but that is mostly just for the simulator not physical hardware.

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is a debouncer. It's been a very long time since I've written any Verilog, but you should be able to find something online searching for "verilog debouncer example" or something along those lines. [This link](https://www.fpga4student.com/2017/04/simple-debouncing-verilog-code-for.html) looked helpful.